# Does "will" always become "would" in the past?

Tags: modal-verbs, past-tense

1)

> Tom: I **will** phone you on Sunday.
>
> Me: Tom said he **would** phone me on Sunday.

2)

> I decided I **will** go to the library. (today)
>
> I decided *yesterday* I **would** go to the library. (tomorrow)

Do I always have to change **will** to **would** when put a statement in the past? What if I say: "I decided yesterday I *will* go to the library." or "Tom said he *will* phone me on Sunday."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question by the same poster](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/117348/2085).

Comment: @tchrist Thanks, but if a question is closed on ELU and is a good fit for ELL we keep them open :) (Now if it's *open* on ELU that's another story.) I appreciate you sharing the link, though! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is permissible (but not obligatory) to use *will* in these circumstances **if** it refers to an event which is still in the future at the time the sentence is uttered.

If on Friday you decide that you will go to the library on Monday ...

- You **may** say *I decided I **would** go to the library on Monday* at any point after your decision.
- You **may** say *I decided (or have decided) I **will** go to the library on Monday* at any point after your decision right up to whatever point marks the end of any practical opportunity for going to the library on Monday.
- After that point you **must** say *I decided I **would** go to the library on Monday*.

Comment: The difference between "I decided" and "I have decided" is that the former implies a specific time that the decision was made, and the latter specifically avoids that specificity.  It is correct to say "Yesterday I decided that I will go to the library on Monday" (assuming it isn't Monday yet), but it is not correct to say "Yesterday I have decided..." under any circumstances.

Comment: That's exactly the main contrast about **past simple & present perfect.**