# can I use 'will' in the past tense sentence?

Tags: tense

Tom **said** that he **will/woul**d save his allowance.

**'will'** and **'would'** are both possible in the given sentence?

Comment: Both are syntactically valid, and could be seen as equivalent in many contexts. Points to note are (1) We *usually* "backshift" to ***would*** in such contexts, and (2) ***Will*** doesn't really work if the activity being referenced ***has** (or **should have**) **already taken place*** by the time of making the "past tense reported speech" utterance. So something like ***Last week** he said he **will** call me **yesterday*** doesn't work at all well for most people in most contexts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does "will" always become "would" in the past?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7556/does-will-always-become-would-in-the-past) (Specific example: ***Tom** said he **would** phone me on Sunday*, so we're even talking about the same ***guy*** as well as the same ***verb**!* :)